# Bootstrap 4 collapsed navbar with 2 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i want my collapsed navbar to be displayed in 2 columns.
I use bootstrap 4.

The fullsize navbar looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/kymuzq

And the collapsed navbar like this:

http://prntscr.com/kymtun

Anyone knows an easy way to make the collapsed navbar with 2 columns so every list item is shown? So on 5 on the left and 5 on the right side.

Very thankful for any help.

Comment: Please show us the code that you already have, we can help modifying it. Ideally, create a SO snippet with [mcve] so that we can easily propose a tested solution. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Nav use flex, so you could use it to display the element of the menu as flex elements.

Add to the element with .navbar.nav class the following classes:

```
.flex-row
```

The elements are in row and not in column

```
.flex-wrap
```

The nav element wrap the children element

Also, you have to use col-6 on every .nav-item, so it splits on two column.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto flex-wrap flex-row">
        <li class="nav-item active col-6">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item col-6">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item col-6">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

You then should use the proper markup for the different breakpoints

Comment: thanks, but the problem is if i add the col-6 class the items of the normal navbar shrink also. http://prntscr.com/kynpqc

Comment: As i said, you have to use the proper markup for the different breakpoint or some media query. If you use sass it will be just easy with  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm).